# Reliable Actor: Console application: Application Ready message never appearing

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, reliable-actors

I am trying a sample application on Reliable Actors provided here:
[enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-actors-get-started)

When I am executing my console application, it is never showing message: "The application is ready". The console windows remains blank and after a long time it shows message: "The thread exited with code 0".

When I set the breakpoint, it shows this:
[image]

Once the code executes, how to deploy the service to Azure trial account. Which project needs to be deployed?

Comment: Did you configure the SF application as (one of the) startup project(s)? Are any errors reported in the SF Explorer after launch?

Comment: Yes I configured. No errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The path: 'fabric/MyApplication...' was incorrect in the local service cluster. Even the local service cluster was not running. Edited the path by right-clicking 'Manage Service Fabric Local Cluster' and it started working.

[image]